# KVM sym link permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, linux-kvm

I have KVM installed on Ubuntu Mate, space filling up on my local drive, so I made a sym link from /var/lib/libvirt/images to /my.foo.external.usb/drive/images

Then I copies over all of my irtual machine images.

Now I fire up te Virtual Machine Manager, and I get

```
unable to access /my.foo.external.usb/drive/images (as UID:64055, GID:129) permission denied
```

External USB is NTFS.

Obviously, it's an ownership/permission problem, but I am stumped now.  I have tried all sorts, but so far, no good.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What options is your NTFS drive mounted with? (See `findmnt -u /my.foo.external.usb/drive`)

Comment: /dev/sda2
              fuseblk
                     rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096